Sign error in the computations of $R_{\theta\phi\theta\phi}$ for the Schwarzschild metric
I am computing the components  of the Riemann tensor for the Schwarzschild metric using the following formula
$R_{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}$=$(\partial_\alpha\Gamma^l_{\beta\mu}-\partial_\beta\Gamma^l_{\alpha\mu}+\Gamma^m_{\beta\mu}\Gamma^l_{\alpha m}-\Gamma^m_{\alpha\mu}\Gamma^l_{\beta m})g_{l\nu}$
But I have a problem with one of the terms
$R_{\theta\phi\theta\phi}$I am getting a sign error. I have consulted a couple of places and I know the answer should be $2mr \sin ^2\theta$ I get $-2mr \sin ^2\theta$  I have redone the computations many times already. Hopefully some external eyes can catch the error more easily.
The christofel symbols that I have computed coincide with those here
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/733433/christoffel-symbols-for-schwarzschild-metric
$R_{\theta\phi\theta\phi}$=$(\partial_\theta\Gamma^\phi_{\phi\theta}-\partial_\phi\Gamma^\phi_{\theta\theta}+\Gamma^m_{\phi\theta}\Gamma^\phi_{\theta m}-\Gamma^m_{\theta\theta}\Gamma^\phi_{\phi m})g_{\phi\phi}$
The only non zero contribution for the third term is when m=$\phi$ and for the fourth term when m=$r$. The second term is 0.
$R_{\theta\phi\theta\phi}$=$(\partial_\theta\cot \theta-0+\Gamma^\phi_{\phi\theta}\Gamma^\phi_{\theta \phi}-\Gamma^r_{\theta\theta}\Gamma^\phi_{\phi r})g_{\phi\phi}$
$R_{\theta\phi\theta\phi}$=$(-\csc^2 \theta+\cot ^2\theta-(-(r-2m))\frac1{r}) r^2 sin^2 \theta=-2mr sin^2 \theta$ $

I don’t feel like going over the full calculation but if you’re just off by a sign, then make sure that you’re using the same metric signature convention as whereever you got the answer from.
